# Capybara with FactoryGirl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, factory-bot

So I want to make sure this is possible and actually doable with what im trying to do.

I had previously been using a `seeds.rb` file to seed the database with test data, this worked for my Capybara integration tests but messed up some of the other unit tests which rely on a `schema.rb` file and Factories to create data.

Can I use a factory to create test data for that particular integration spec. Something like this for a factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name   Faker::Name.last_name
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password "password"
  end
end
```

Then I have a super simple spec which logins to a site in Capybara:

```
  it 'Check correct login' do
    visit('/sign_in')
    page.fill_in 'user_email', :with => 'test@test.com'
    page.fill_in 'user_password', :with => 'p4ssw0rd'
    click_button('Sign In')
  end
```

This is hitting a Sqlite database, can I insert my factory and it will work using capybara? Im really not familiar with factorygirl, but is it actually creating data in the database and then just removing it?

I don't commonly see Capybara used with FactoryGirl in a lot of the examples I search online, is there a reason for that?

edit:
Here is what I have currently:

```
  it 'Check correct login' do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    visit('/d/users/sign_in')
    page.fill_in 'user_email', :with => user.email
    page.fill_in 'user_password', :with => user.password
    click_button('Log In')
    page.assert_text('Signed in successfully.')
  end
```

I was able to take a screenshot and confirm that the forms are getting filled in with a random username/password, but using DB Browser for SQlite I don't seem to see the actual data in the database getting populated (Which might be difficult since once the spec is done it's deleted right?) but I can't tell if it's actually creating the data or not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work fine w/o many hitches. You'll need to instantiate your User object in your test as this looks like a 'sign-in'.

You can create the object a couple of different ways.

(1)

```
describe 'Test' do
  let(:user){ create :user }
  ...
  it 'Specific Test' do
  ...
```

Note that `let!(:user){...}` creates immediately and `let(:user){...}` will only create user when the `user` is called. You will then be able to access `user` in all your tests.

(2)

```
describe 'Test' do
  before do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create( :user )
  end
  it 'Specific Test' do
  ...
```

Here you will be able to access `@user` in all your tests.

Let us know if that works and if not what error you're getting.

EDIT:

If your FG file looked like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name Faker::Name.first_name
    last_name   Faker::Name.last_name
    email Faker::Internet.email
    password "password"
    work
  end
end
```

You could associate work like this:

```
let(:user){ create :user, work: 'Some Place' }
@user = FactoryGirl.create(:user, work: 'Some Place')
```

Comment: What do I use for the fill_in's? `Faker::Internet.email` and `password`?

Also is there any "best practice" in the "let!" vs "let"

Comment: I've not used Faker, actually, but that looks right. You can also just put in a string `'fake-email@email.org'` and `'password'` in the FactoryGirl file. You can also put associations in the FG file by just leaving them blank and referencing them when you instantiate: `let!(:user){create :user, work: 'Some Place'}` As for the `let!` or `let` it's mostly a lazy loading issue -- no need to load things you don't use, but if you don't know what you're doing, your test might fail cause your object you think is there isn't! :-) I'll add some code to the answer.

Comment: @msmith1114  For the fill_in's you would use either `page.fill_in 'user_email', with: user.email` or `page.fill_in 'user_email', with: @user.email` depending on whether you're using `let` or creating your own instance variables in a before block

Comment: Well, it produced a random email/password. But my application gave "invalid login" essentially. How can I check that whatever was created was actually placed in the database temporarily?  Im running this with `Capybara.run_server = true` w/poltergeist and my test database is set to sqlite. Im running `RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load` before each run and ensuring im running the tests in the test environment.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole Looks like changing `config.use_transactional_fixtures = false` instead of `true` in `rails_helper` fixes THIS, but causes all other rspec unit tests (Which I didn't write, but they are standard rspec unit tests) to fail.

Is there some way around this? Im not I really understand what changing it to `false` even does and why it works with it as `false`. Maybe somehow I can just make MY tests make it `false` but all other rspec tests as `true`? Maybe in test_helper.rb or something?

Comment: @msmith1114 When running JS tests the test and app run in separate threads with their own database connections so transactional testing can't be used (otherwise database objects are only visible to the thread that creates them since they're never actually committed).  Use database_cleaner with the recommended config - https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner#rspec-with-capybara-example

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I see, So I guess in that case why did setting `use_transactional_fixtures` = false work? I understand what your saying, but if it's in a separate thread wouldn't it still not work even with it set to false?

Comment: @msmith1114 When it's set to false, a transaction isn't wrapped around each test, objects actually get committed and all threads can see the objects created.  However, the database isn't then automatically cleaned between each test so all your other tests fail because the database is full of records the tests don't expect.  database_cleaner handles that cleaning of the database between tests by swapping between transactional mode when it's usable (fast), and truncation or deletion when running JS capable tests.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes more sense. Is using Factories honestly a suggested way of setting up data going forward for Integration testing? Im new to it, but it seems to have a lot of hurdles...and I guess I wonder if it really makes the most sense compared to say...seeding data in the database (Im really doing this to preserve unit tests that are damaged by seeded data). But I'd like the opinion of someone that writes it a lot :).

Sidenote: Where should I be putting this database cleaner config anyways? My test_helper file in general? or just it's own helper file.

Comment: @msmith1114 I really like factories. They give your objects a consistency through your tests that make things easier to debug and makes results more expected. They are also generally cleaner, shorter code. But there are definitely people that feel that it is an unnecessary layer to object creation. For sidenote: I always put my database cleaner config in my spec_helper.rb inside the the `Rspec.configure` block in a `config.before(:each) do`

Comment: Thanks, thats what I had to end up doing (except in rails_helper.rb) actually as database_cleaner didn't seem to want to accept the 'require' in any other file (for whatever reason). But yeah I can certainly see why some people would find it unneccesary, but it does def. allow for a cleaner database. Thanks again for your help!